# NAS disk which can go to sleep

Tags: hard-disk, nas

I am buying a disk for my home-made NAS server. I will not access my server very often so I am planning to spin down (put disk to sleep) when not in use.

I was thinking about WD Red or Seagate Ironwolf since they are optimized for nas. But then again... NAS disks usually are not ment to be spinned down since this puts a lot of stress on the disk. They dont even support hdparam and you have to rely on third party tools to put them to sleep (https://withblue.ink/2016/07/15/what-i-learnt-from-using-wd-red-disks-to-build-a-home-nas.html).

**Which disk would you recommend me for my use case?** Would you go with WD Red, Ironwolf or some other disk? Do you know any disk which specifically supports hdparm?